# HOSTNAME set in environment but not visible to gmake

Tags: bash, makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

This has plagued me on and off for years. Can anyone explain why `$(HOSTNAME)` doesn't expand to the environment value HOSTNAME? Googling various combinations of "make", "hostname", "gmake", "not set" and so forth hasn't been fruitful for me.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ set | egrep 'HOSTNAME|USER'
HOSTNAME=intrepid
USER=jcomeau
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat Makefile 
%.test:
    set | grep $*
%.env:
    echo $($*)
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make HOSTNAME.test
set | grep HOSTNAME
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING='set | grep HOSTNAME'
HOSTNAME=intrepid
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make HOSTNAME.env
echo 

jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make USER.test
set | grep USER
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING='set | grep USER'
USER=jcomeau
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make USER.env
echo jcomeau
jcomeau
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the difference between a shell variable and an environment variable.  Try running "export HOSTNAME" before your test and see the difference.

Also, compare the difference in output between "set" and "env".

Answer (score 2):

When you start a subprocess in a shell (perhaps by running the `make` command), it inherits the shell's original environment variables, plus all "exported" variables from inside the shell. If the shell's original environment didn't have $HOSTNAME and $HOSTNAME wasn't exported, it won't be in the environment of a spawned process.

Run `export` to see a list of exported variables. On my system, $HOSTNAME isn't in the exports by default. If you want HOSTNAME to be available in a spawned process, you can `export HOSTNAME` on the command line, or in your .bashrc/profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export hostname you can use:

```
export SERVERIP=$(hostname --ip-address)
echo $SERVERIP
```

Comment: This is exporting the IP address and not the hostname